# Find polynomials $f(x), g(x)$, and $h(x)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math

> Find polynomials $f(x), g(x)$, and $h(x)$, if they exist, such that
>   for all $x$,   $$\mid f(x)\mid-\mid g(x) \mid+h(x)=   \begin{cases}  
>  -1, & \text{if}~x<-1 \\   3x+2, & \text{if}~-1\leq x\leq 0 \\  
> -2x+2, & \text{if}~x>0\\ \end{cases}$$

The solution are $f(x) := 3(x+1)/2$ , $g(x) := 5x/2$ and $h(x) := (1 – 2x)/2$ meet the requirements.

Is anyone can explain to me why a particular solution can be determined most easily by solving three linear equations:
$–f + g + h = –1 $, $f + g + h = 3x + 2$ , $f – g + h = –2x + 2$ ?

Namely it is a question of PUTNAM 1999.

Comment: I have I already know that there exists similar questions, but my question is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $f, g, h$ are polynomials, they cannot have corners.  However at $x=-1, 0$ there are corners.  So at least one among $f, g$ must change sign at each of these points.  As they are linear, they cannot change signs at two points, so exactly one function must change its sign at each of these points.

It does not matter which you assume change points, the final solution will remain the same, (except for a sign variation - note that if $(f, g, h)$ is a solution, so is $(\pm f, \pm g, h)$.